# ArcGIS Online Experience Builder - Are different default basemaps possible for 2 map widgets using the same Map data?

Tags: basemap, widget, arcgis-experience-builder

On the Water Bore page I'm working on, I want to be able to select a bore location from the main map widget and on an inset map widget, automatically zoom to that bore location overlaid onto an aerial basemap.

Both maps widgets contain the same Map data, which has an NZ topographic basemap.

Everything is working as I want it  - except that I can't set the inset map widget to default to the aerial basemap  - it defaults to NZ topographic and I have to select aerial basemap with a basemap widget.

Is it possible to select a different default basemap for the same map in different map widgets?

Some clarification - I'd like the user to be able to do what they like with the big map (zoom in and out, choose their own basemap etc.) - but when they select a specific bore - I'd like them to immediately see a zoomed-in aerial view of the bore.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have two different default basemaps for two instances of the same map, but the solution to achieve the same effect is quite easy.

Create a copy of the map and change the basemap to the one required  - save this with a suitable name.

Import this new map as a data source in Experience Builder.

Connect the inset map widget to this new map.

This works straight away without even having to remove the connection to the original map - although removing the original map as a source for the widget makes no difference.

[image]